# CosmosDB performance issue with Array_Contains

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I’m currently looking at improving the performance of a query that’s using Array_Contains in CosmosDB, for some reason it’s not using the index I’m yet to figure out why.

SELECT COUNT(1) as COUNT FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.statusList, '2c89f4c1b3ac44828dsdfdb6f6c4bd') = false

Attached are the query stats.

Does anyone have any idea what’s the issue might be or how to improve the query performance?

FYI this performance is on index v2, which was newly created collection. Also does anyone how we can figure out when index version a old collection is running?

Here are the performance stats.
[image: performance result]

Comment: Looking into this. Will revert here when I have more information.

Answer (score 0):

ARRAY_CONTAINS normally will use the index when using an aggregate such as Count() when the filter = true. However it doesn't use it when the filter is = false.

This was a known issue and a fix is being worked on now. Likely will not be fully deployed until June. Should require no changes on your end when it does. The query will just improve automatically.